# Show multiple duplicate links even from the same user

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, user-experience

Sometimes when we find duplicates, it's not clear which of a number of possible duplicates is the most appropriate.  If there are multiple duplicate nominations *by different users,* the question ends up with links to all the nominated duplicates if and when it is indeed closed as a duplicate.  But this doesn't work if the nominations are by the same user.

I wanted to mark [Bash: how to properly slice new lines with grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803063/bash-how-to-properly-slice-new-lines-with-grep) as a duplicate of either one of two questions, and manually pasted "Possible duplicate of XXX" as comments to the question before wielding my [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) dupe hammer to actually close it.  But alas, the comments I had so meticulously pasted in were *both* removed, with no trace of the link to a possibly relevant different duplicate candidate.  (I then manually pasted a "Possible duplicate of XXX" comment a second time to at least leave some sort of pointer.)

I am posting this as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to suggest that the above behavior should actually work like I expected.

As a workaround, you can get somebody who isn't a gold badge to suggest another duplicate before you close the question.  This is clunky at best, although the nice folks in the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) have been happy to help out in the past in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But alas, the comments I had so meticulously pasted in were both removed

[That bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified) will probably never be fixed. Any comment on a question which contains the word "duplicate" and a link to another question on the same site will be removed if the question is closed as a duplicate.

> with no trace of the link to a possibly relevant different duplicate candidate

There is though:

[image]

Links to other questions used in question, comments and answers (regardless of whether they are deleted) will show up in the "Linked" list to the right of the question.

However, there's now since a week or two a new feature: [Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links).

You, as a gold [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag badge holder, can click the "edit" link to add duplicates to a question that was closed as a duplicate.